# How to vertically and horizontally align text in the window?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center align the text both vertically and horizontally within a div in the window, and I want it to work on both portrait and landscape modes on the iPhone. Here is my code but it don't work well.

HTML:

```
<div class="mainTeaser">
    <img src="teaser.jpg" />
    <span class="teaserWrap">
        <span class="headline">TEXT</span>
        <span class="subline">TEXT</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mainTeaser {
    position: relative;
}
.mainTeaser img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.mainTeaser .teaserWrap {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: With iPhone orientation you mean portrait and landscape? Or do you want the text to be vertically & horizontally aligned? Please use this fiddle and make it look like your project: http://jsfiddle.net/dqosnbqc/

Comment: The technique you are trying requires to set width and height to .teaserWrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use background image instead, with `background-size:cover`, and use `transform` for centering the text.

You'll also need to set all the containers to `height:100%`, so it covers the entire viewport height.

```css
html, body {
    height :100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.mainTeaser {
    position: relative;
    height :100%;
}
.mainTeaser {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature") center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.mainTeaser .teaserWrap {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainTeaser">
    <span class="teaserWrap">
        <span class="headline">TEXT</span>
        <span class="subline">TEXT</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for Absolute to behave in that manner it needs predefined width's and height's

see bellow in this version i just made the absolute div width 100% with text align center it leaves a little less room for error when it comes to fixed size's

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.mainTeaser {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.align {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
}
.mainTeaser img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.mainTeaser .teaserWrap {}
```

```html
<div class="mainTeaser">
  <div class="align">
    <img src="teaser.jpg" />
    <span class="teaserWrap">
        <span class="headline">TEXT</span>
    <span class="subline">TEXT</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```